# Multiple file loading matlab

Tags: matlab, multiple-file-upload

I want to load multiple files in few folders and to plot figures for each. I'm quite naive to matlab environment, I did something dirty like this!:

```
foldername1='K_S/';
foldername2='L_J/';
foldername3='P_O/';

extension='*.pro';

name1=strcat(foldername1, extension);
name2=strcat(foldername2, extension);
name3=strcat(foldername3, extension);

fileset1=dir(name1);
fileset2=dir(name2);
fileset3=dir(name3);

a = [];
b = [];
c = [];

for i = 1:length(fileset1)

    a=load(strcat(foldername1, fileset1(i).name)); 
    b=load(strcat(foldername2, fileset2(i).name)); 
    c=load(strcat(foldername3, fileset3(i).name)); 


    figure
    sub1=plot(a(:,1),a(:,2),'b'), hold on
    sub2=plot(a(:,1),a(:,3),'r')
    ylabel('score')
    xlabel('trial')
    legend([sub1, sub2],'sub1','sub2')
    legend boxoff
    title(sprintf('Dyad K S: %d',i));
    axis square

    figure
    sub1=plot(b(:,1),b(:,2),'b'), hold on
    sub2=plot(b(:,1),b(:,3),'r')
    ylabel('score')
    xlabel('trial')
    legend([sub1, sub2],'sub1','sub2')
    legend boxoff
    title(sprintf('Dyad L J: %d',i));
    axis square

    figure
    sub1=plot(c(:,1),c(:,2),'b'), hold on
    sub2=plot(c(:,1),c(:,3),'r')
    ylabel('score')
    xlabel('trial')
    legend([sub1, sub2],'sub1','sub2')
    legend boxoff
    title(sprintf('Dyad P O: %d',i));
    axis square

end
```

Any help would be appreciated on how to make it smarter.

Thank you!

Comment: use `fullfile` command instead of `strcat` for file paths and names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [cells](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) in matlab, which allows to store multiple obejcts into a single variable.
Something like that

```
foldername ={'K_S/', 'L_J/', 'P_O/'};

extension='*.pro';

for k = 1:length(foldername)

    name=strcat(foldername{k}, extension);

    fileset=dir(name);

    a = [];                               

    for i = 1:length(fileset)

        a=load(strcat(foldername{k}, fileset(i).name)); 


        figure
        sub1=plot(a(:,1),a(:,2),'b'), hold on
        sub2=plot(a(:,1),a(:,3),'r')
        ylabel('score')
        xlabel('trial')
        legend([sub1, sub2],'sub1','sub2')
        legend boxoff
        title(sprintf(['Dyad' strrep(foldername{k}, '_', ' ') ': %d'],i));
        axis square


    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much @DomDev for your suggestion.          Here I'm wondering the name : 'name=strcat(foldername{k}, extension);' must be a cell , right?

Comment: No, not necessarily.  Because it is in a loop, it will overwrite itself for each folder name. However, if you want to save the variable 'name' for later use, then it should be a cell.

Comment: Please upvote the question and mark it as an answer if it helped you :)

Comment: I just arranged the code so the title gets updated correctly

Comment: When I run it , it says "Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object", and points at -> fileset=dir(name{k}); But when I initialize name as an cell like name={ strcat(foldername{k}, extension) }; It plots the contents in first folder and  says  "Index exceeds matrix dimensions".

Comment: Thanks @DomDev but I'm not able to upvote it because I'm new to the forum and don't have much reputation!

Comment: Don't forget to add a "clear all;" and "clc;" at the start of your code. This will erase all the variables in the memory of Matlab, which allows you to run the code from a clean start.

Comment: Sorry, I just changed my code. It's only "fileset = dir(name)". I'm sorry, I don't have the files so I could verify the code.